# The BEST way to read some strings and print the longest one in GO

Tags: string, go, design-patterns, find, match

I'm getting crazy.
I'm trying to write a program which reads some strings (in my case 5) and prints the longest one.
I have googled and searched here but i haven't fond anything...

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 string
    fmt.Scan(&t1, &t2, &t3, &t4, &t5)
    var l1, l2, l3, l4, l5 int
    var max int = -50000
    l1 = len(t1)
    l2 = len(t2)
    l3 = len(t3)
    l4 = len(t4)
    l5 = len(t5)
    var longest string = ""
    if l1 > max {
        l1 = max
    }
    if l2 > max {
        l2 = max
    }
    if l3 > max {
        l3 = max
    }
    if l4 > max {
        l4 = max
    }
    if l5 > max {
        l5 = max
    }

    fmt.Println(max)
}
```

Comment: Why not use a loop?

Comment: I thought, but i don't know how to apply it to the code.

Comment: Then you probably want to start with the section of [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/1) about flow control.

Comment: Isn't this assignment backwards? `l1 = max`. You want to track the largest max, so you have to update it sometime. (fix it in 5 places) And you don't have to set `max` to -5000; 0 will do. The -5000 makes us think there's something special going on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I wrote simple codes to do that. follow [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/basics/17) as `Flimzy` said above and get more understanding about Go loops.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    
    t := make([]string, 5)
         //scan strings first
    for  i := range t {
        fmt.Scan(&t[i])
    }

    var longest string = ""
        // compare longest
    for _, s := range t {
        if len(longest) < len(s) {
            longest = s
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(`longest := `,longest)
}
```

You can reduce first loop and do it below way. Scan string and compare in one loop.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    t := make([]string, 5)

    var longest string = ""
    for i, _ := range t {
        fmt.Scan(&t[i])
        if len(longest) < len(t[i]) {
            longest = t[i]
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(`longest := `,longest)
}
```